# Validate two TextBox.Text values to be distinct

Tags: wpf, xaml

Grab two TextBox and say that you need to validate that their content are distinct strings.

Example :

- Correct result : prefix1, prefix2
- Incorrect result : prefix1, prefix1

To do that task I thought about using a MultiBinding but two problems arises then :

- Where should it be placed ? currently it is on a dummy TextBox
- Even using that dummy TextBox, the ValidationRule is never called

Not sure whether this approach is correct, how would you do that ?

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
    <Binding Path="GradientPrefix"
                Source="{StaticResource Indices}"
                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
    <Binding Path="ColorPrefix"
                Source="{StaticResource Indices}"
                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
    <MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
        <gpl2Xaml:DistinctStringValidationRule />
    </MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
</MultiBinding>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution using a BindingGroup !

Error at BindingGroup level :

[image]

Error at BindingGroup and field levels :

[image]

No errors :

[image]

Here's the code :

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <gpl2Xaml:Indices x:Key="Indices"
                          ColorIndex="1"
                          ColorPrefix="MyColor"
                          GradientIndex="1"
                          GradientPrefix="MyColor" />
    </Window.Resources>
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Indices}"
              Style="{StaticResource gridInError}"
              Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}">
            <Grid.BindingGroup>
                <BindingGroup>
                    <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                        <gpl2Xaml:DistinctValidationRule />
                    </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                </BindingGroup>
            </Grid.BindingGroup>
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxGradientPrefix"
                     Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
                     TextChanged="TextBoxGradientPrefix_OnTextChanged"
                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}">
                <Binding Path="GradientPrefix"
                         Source="{StaticResource Indices}"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <gpl2Xaml:StringValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxColorPrefix"
                     Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
                     TextChanged="TextBoxColorPrefix_OnTextChanged"
                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}">
                <Binding Path="ColorPrefix"
                         Source="{StaticResource Indices}"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <gpl2Xaml:StringValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Extra code to trigger validation every time :

```
    private void TextBoxGradientPrefix_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();
    }

    private void TextBoxColorPrefix_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();
    }
```

And the validation rule :

```
public class DistinctValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var bindingGroup = value as BindingGroup;
        if (bindingGroup == null) return new ValidationResult(false, "Not a BindingGroup");

        var o = bindingGroup.Items[0] as Indices;
        if (o == null) return new ValidationResult(false, "Not an Indices");

        if (o.ColorPrefix == o.GradientPrefix)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Color prefix and Gradient prefix must be distinct.");

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the definition for `validationTemplate`.